# How to call a command as a function

Tags: python, function, command, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a verify bot for my discord server (and for fun). I noticed I cannot call a command as a function. I've kinda made a solution only for the single python file that the function is on. But when I want to call the `say` command in a seperate python file it doesn't work.

**Alternatively:** How can I use `channel.send()` in a regular function

### Code:

```
async def say_c(message, channel_id):
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)

    await channel.send(message)

def say(*args, channel_id):
    message = ""

    for word in args:
        message = message + word + " "

    bot.loop.create_task(say_c(message, channel_id))
```

*Note:* `say_c` is the one that puts something on the discord server but `say` is the function that I call in the file. This works but doesn't work on a separate python file.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use it from an other "file" (usually called a `module`), they need to be in the same workspace, that is, they must be in the same folder (there are other possible setups as well, but that's out of the scope of this question).

```
my_discord_bot/
├── discord_bot.py
├── other.py
```

Let's say you have your above posted code in `discord_bot.py`.
To be able to call it from `other.py`, you need to put something like this into your `other.py` file:

```
from discord_bot import say

say('hello')
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, but this is what I've been doing the whole time but doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain how do you execute your code? What error message/exception do you get when you try calling it?

Comment: It doesn't show an error, It just doesn't run the function. Well, there are 2 functions that I use, `say function` is the one that I call in a different python file and the `say_c function` is the function that say something to the discord server, I call the `say_c function` with the loop.create_task, look at my code and maybe it makes more sense. For some odd reason, the *say function only works where it defines it*, I import the say command like how you would import a function.

Comment: How does this "different python file" import your `say` function? You should upload your code to github or repl.it (https://repl.it/languages/python3) because having no error message makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry for late ping, well I imported it like this `import say`, and `from bot import say`.